View Not Updating When Using Background Actor to Write Data to Container
I’m currently studying SwiftData I want to write and save data to my container application from the ContentView and at the same time using modelActor I also want to save from background thread.
Base on my understanding, either way , should update my View when change happens, but this do not happen when I save data from the background.
What is wrong on my code:
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Test-SwiftData
//
//  Created by Damiano Miazzi on 01/08/2024.
//

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                    } label: {
                        HStack{
                            Text(item.text)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button {
                        Task{
                            let act = DataManager(modelContainer: modelContext.container)
                            await act.insert()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Add BK")
                    }

                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date(), text: "Main")
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
            try? modelContext.save()
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}


@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    var text: String
    
    init (timestamp: Date = Date(), text: String) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.text = text
    }
}
@main
struct Test_SwiftDataApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Item.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}



@ModelActor
actor DataManager {
    
    @MainActor
    public init(modelContainer: ModelContainer,mainActor _: Bool) {
        let modelContext = modelContainer.mainContext
        modelExecutor = DefaultSerialModelExecutor(modelContext: modelContext)
        self.modelContainer = modelContainer
    }
    
    func insert(){
        let item = Item(timestamp: Date(), text: "BK")
        modelContext.insert(item)
        try? modelContext.save()
    }
    
}



The problem with calling insert then save is you are also saving any other changes made to the context. That's why usually the context is saved when the app suspends so it can save all the changes in one go. Then you don't need a background context for these simple inserts. For long running inserts then you could make a new context for each async task, however it probably will have the same issue the UI won't update so you will need to go down the persistent history route.

Why do you mark the init of DataManager as MainActor? I've read that ModelActors target the same queue they're created on. Additionally you call the init in a regular Task {} on the view, which would inherit MainActor. Are you sure your DataManager is actually on a background thread?

We are facing the same issue, after investigating it for few days it seems to be a problem with iOS 18 and SwiftData, according to this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/759364 a fix is being made, below you will find the temporal workaround suggested by Apple engineer:
For a workaround before the issue is fixed on the framework side, you might consider observing .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave notification and triggering a SwiftUI update from the notification handler. For example:
import Combine

extension NotificationCenter {
    var managedObjectContextDidSavePublisher: Publishers.ReceiveOn<NotificationCenter.Publisher, DispatchQueue> {
        return publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave).receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    }
}

struct MySwiftDataView: View {
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    
    // Use the notification time as a state to trigger a SwiftUI update.
    // Use a state more appropriate to your app, if any.
    @State private var contextDidSaveDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text("\(item.timestamp)")
            }
            // Refresh the view by changing its `id`.
            // Use a way more appropriate to your app, if any.
            .id(contextDidSaveDate)
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.managedObjectContextDidSavePublisher) { _ in
            contextDidSaveDate = .now
        }
    }
}

This will refresh every view you attach the contextDidSaveDate to as .id(contextDidSaveDate) when a context save() is being performed.

I just hit the same issue and applied this workaround, works nicely except for changes in Annotations on a MapView.

It works like a charm with Xcode 16/iOS 18. Thank you.

This is due to a bug in SwiftData, you need to use the ModelContext that is bound to the main actor.
Using the main actor is of course not optimal but this is a temporary workaround until this bug is fixed and if the actor is used for simple operations like inserting, updating or deleting single objects it should be a minor problem.
As a workaround for now you can modify the init of DataManager 
init(with container: ModelContainer) {
    context = container.mainContext
}

For the actor I think you need to remove the modelContext property because one is added anyway by the macro and initialise it like this instead, note that we use @MainActor and the mainContext property from the passed container
@MainActor
public init(modelContainer: ModelContainer, mainActor _: Bool) {
    let modelContext = modelContainer.mainContext
    modelExecutor = DefaultSerialModelExecutor(modelContext: modelContext)
    self.modelContainer = modelContainer
}


I tried but get error , Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

I updated the answer with another solution

I update my question, with more simplify code, and with your code, still not work: I can only see the change after I close and reopen the app. How can I update the UI after the change.

Your latest edit works fine for me and the UI gets updated.

This is not a good solution, you will block the UI and might cause a data race. @ModelActor is meant to be used in the background, I am currently facing the same exact issue and still hasn't managed to find a solution

You did not mentioned it, you just mentioned it will be bound to the main actor, you should edit your response, also, clearly the question was meant for background tasks.

@JoakimDanielson see my answer for the workaround that was suggested by one of Apple engineers/developers

@ia244 I haven’t tested your solution but it looks better for true long running background tasks while I guess my solution is more suited for simple operations like single inserts or deletes. I thought I was clear in what I wrote in my answer but maybe you are right and I could have been clearer.
